# Can't remove python 3.10 from ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: apt, gnome, python, python3

Ubuntu 20.04 comes with python 3.8 as default version. I installed python 3.10 by adding deadsnakes ppa. While running "sudo apt remove python3.10" it gives following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python3.10-minimal : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is to be installed
                  Recommends: python3.10 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How do I fix this? I ran "sudo apt --fix-broken install" as suggested; it gives following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 68.6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 206497 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py', which is also in package 
libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Happened to me today, please see: this answer [Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while upgrading python3.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402410/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-while-upgrading-python3-10)

```
ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i libpython3.10-minimal

sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpython3.10-minimal:amd64.* /tmp

sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It fixed my probelm.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that you are using python3.8 as the default python version.

```
sudo update-alternatives  --set python3 /usr/bin/python3.8
sudo update-alternatives  --set python /usr/bin/python3.8
```

Now, try purging the PPA to remove python3.10

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```