# Software Updater - The package system is broken python3.10

Tags: apt, updates, python

I am currently using Ubuntu Gnome 20.04 and when I try to run updates via the Software Updater I get the following "The package system is broken" Error:

```
    Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:

python3.10: Depends: python3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal2 is installed
            Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is installed
python3.10-minimal: Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is installed
                    Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2ubuntu1.3 is installed
```

I cannot recall installing an additional Python Version, hence this error confuses me. Up to this point I think I have 2 Python Versions installed and this might cause some issues. Regardless, running `sudo apt-get install -f` gives me

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Unfortunately I am new to Linux, and do not know what to do from here. I googled the error, but people with similar problems have different outputs, so I hesitated copy pasting commands into my terminal.  Moreover, I literally only use Visual Studio Code for coding with Python and Riders for coding with C# and I have nothing else installed on this system.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us: What flavour of Ubuntu are you using? Did you change the python version? If so, why? Do you have third party software on your system (any software you didn't get from Ubuntus official repositories)? Did you add PPAs or any other sources?

Comment: Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1402410/124466