# Update problem in connection with python on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: updates

Some time later after installing newer python, after about 10 - 20 updates got this problem. Tried to fix it, but did not succeed.

[image]

How to take back this python configuration?

I send another picture: [Picture from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAgEy.png)

Comment: Are you using any external repositories?  If you are using python repositories to provide 3.10 those could break in certain circumstances, and that can lead to newer versions not being installed or missing dependencies elsewhere in the chain, and when you have third party repositories added it becomes much harder to really fix these things.

Comment: Is [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1402892/1438484) the same issue?

Comment: Changing the python version can break your system. I suggest that you undo these changes. If you need a specific python version for some task, use an environment

Comment: Im new on linux. I wanted to install newest phyton, but something has gone wrong. When the problem is in the external repositories, how i remove them, or how I remove all the phtyon files, except the original, and when they are broken, how I fix them. Where to start?

Comment: I found the solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402456/unmet-dependencies-for-python-3-10. I thank you all who tried to help me!