# Problem with software updating - package conflicts

Tags: 20.04, updates, dpkg, software-center

I have problems updating my Ubuntu 20.04. When I click on "update software". I got this message:

[image]

I followed the answer here: [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in/433510#433510)

I tried `sudo dpkg -P python3.10` and I got:

```
(Reading database ... 256018 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python3.10 (3.10.4-1+focal2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
```

Then I try `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libfwupdplugin1 libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
  python3.10-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 89 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 68.6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 256000 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) ..
.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10
.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/_sysconfigdata__linux_x86_64-linux-gnu
.py', which is also in package libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) .
..
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.1
0.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py', which is also in package l
ibpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 3.10.4-1+focal1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this problem please?

Comment: seems like the dependencies packages are conflict with third party repositories. try to run `sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.10' | awk '{print $2}')` and then `sudo apt purge libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev python3.10 python3.10-minimal python3.10-dev python3.10-venv` and then `sudo apt install python3.10`.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri it seems to work! Please write your comment as an answer to get a bounty. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many others observed similar problems, see below.
There are several posted answers, I would refer you to [Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while upgrading python3.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402410/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-while-upgrading-python3-10), which is very recent, and evidently has quickly reached (and helped) a lot of users.

You have to do some manual work like this.
Slight variations might be required, please check references and post feedback.

1. Remove packages with `sudo apt remove libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib`
2. Move packages info with `sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64.* /tmp` (you could check the presence with `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i libpython3.10-stdlib`). Likewise for `libpython3.10-minimal`.
3. Reinstall with `sudo apt --fix-broken install`.

**Related**:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71871921/no-way-to-update-python3-10-on-my-linux-mint-mate-20-3-una
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.9/+bug/1969191
3. https://forum.zorin.com/t/python-dependency-errors/17812
4. https://discuss.python.org/t/stuck-upgrading-parts-of-3-10-from-3-10-3-to-3-10-4/15183
5. https://serveanswer.com/questions/unmet-dependencies-when-installing-pyqt5-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

This issue already fixed in [github of the Deadsnakes PPA's](https://github.com/deadsnakes/issues/issues/207)

```
sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.10' | awk '{print $2}')
```

or

```
sudo apt purge libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev python3.10 python3.10-minimal python3.10-dev python3.10-venv
sudo apt install python3.10
```

Hope this helps.